# Android: Overlay a picture (jpg) with transparency

Tags: android, image, transparency

I have a picture (jpg) that I want to display on the screen.
Additionally the picture should be covered partially by a transparent effect.
The transparent cover should be dynamic. So e.g. each day more of the picture is shown.
Here a picture to show what I mean: 
[image]

I have the picture without the gray cover and want to add this cover but in different steps.

Can someone give me a hint how to do that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this simply with widgets:

[FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) is the general mechanism for overlaying a view on top of another:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>
<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your Java code you can dynamically set the transparency of your overlay:

```
View overlay = (View) findViewById(R.id.overlay);
int opacity = 200; // from 0 to 255
overlay.setBackgroundColor(opacity * 0x1000000); // black with a variable alpha
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =
    new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 100);
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
overlay.setLayoutParams(params);
overlay.invalidate(); // update the view
```

Comment: thank you! This is a great hint. I have another question: I want to cover only a part of the underlying picture. Can I do this with your suggestion?

Comment: yes, just size the overlay view accordingly (android_layout_height="100dp") and set its gravity (android:layout_gravity="bottom") etc.

Comment: thx, I will try it. But I have to set that in the java code, because the size of the overlay should change each hour.

Comment: @Matthew Willis: I need your help again. Your code works nice! But I dont know how to change the height of the overlay from the java code: overlay.setHeight(122) or something like that in order to set this android_layout_height="100dp" dynamically. Probably I have to use this: overlay.setLayoutParams(params)?

Comment: yup, that's right. I updated the code using Gravity.BOTTOM and layout parameters.

Comment: Great! Consider accepting answers that help you using the green checkmark. It benefits both you and the answerer and encourages others to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: @Willis: I have still an issue. I have to set a value for heiht and width for the framelayout. otherwise the view fills the whole screen with fill_parent. But I do not know how big the picture is, because it can be changed at runtime. _Can you see a solution?

Comment: In the code I posted I have wrap_content set on the FrameLayout. Does this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. The View with fill_parent eg for height fills the rest of the screen and other things like my buttons are gone.

Comment: Are you setting large width/height on the overlay view?

Comment: No I am using no specific values: <View
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

Comment: It might be a good idea to start a new question posting your full layout

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this where the canvas is coming from an `onDraw()` request:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
Rect r = new Rect(); 
paint.setColor(0x80808080); // translucent gray 
r.right = iDisplayWidth-1; 
r.left = 0; 
r.top = iDisplayHeight/2; 
r.bottom = iDisplayHeight-1; 
canvas.drawRect(r, paint); // fill with gray
```

Comment: how do I overlay this over my picture?

Comment: Draw the bitmap to a canvas, then add this after you draw the bitmap.