# Having activity greyed out and having two buttons to select

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there any way I can make two buttons appear up and have the main UI greyed out without calling the pause method in android? sort of like robo defender. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Robo Defender, but a common way to do this sort of this is with an overlay.  You can put a view over your activity with an opacity of ~30%.  This view can have a grey image that cover everything but your buttons.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example link? This sounds really cool.

Comment: There's an example of something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211912/android-overlay-a-picture-jpg-with-transparency